# Creating an array of dates efficiently?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb

I have an `availabilities` collection. Inside this collection could be a few entries that are date based for example:

```
{
  "_id": "64b03ed794d87927a3066e13",
  "startDateTime": "2023-07-07T18:00:00.000Z",
  "endDateTime": "2023-07-12T15:00:00.000Z",
  "availabilityType": "blackout"
}
{
  "_id": "64b03eb094d87927a3066ddb",
  "startDateTime": "2023-07-03T18:00:00.000Z",
  "endDateTime": "2023-07-06T15:00:00.000Z",
  "availabilityType": "blackout"
}
```

I am trying to figure out the best way to create an array of dates for the month and if there is an “availability” for some of the days, then return that within the date array. I thought about creating an array of days using javascript but then I’d have to iterate for each day to see there are any `availabilities` on the day; this seems very inefficient.

Ideally what I am looking to build is something similar to the following:

```
[
  {
    "date": "2023-07-01",
    "availabilityType": "available"
  },
  {
    "date": "2023-07-02",
    "availabilityType": "available"
  },
  {
    "date": "2023-07-03",
    "availabilityType": "booked" // because there was an availability entry in the collection that is marked as booked
  },
  {
    "date": "2023-07-04",
    "availabilityType": "booked" // because there was an availability entry in the collection that is marked as booked
  },
  {
    "date": "2023-07-05",
    "availabilityType": "booked" // because there was an availability entry in the collection that is marked as booked
  },
  {
    "date": "2023-07-06",
    "availabilityType": "booked" // because there was an availability entry in the collection that is marked as booked
  },
  ... etc up to July 31
]
```

Any suggestions on how this might be done?

Comment: You know the number of days in a month. You have a collection of date ranges. Iterate those ranges, track which are unavailable (remove from a set, set a flag in an array, ...). The size of the input data matters, but how **much** it matters, we don't really know.

Comment: There aren't a collection of date ranges though, there *might* be an entry or two of some ranges. I know I can iterate and do this manually but that just seems inefficient to query on the collection for each day to see if there are any dates I need to change the availableType for

Comment: You have a collection called `availabilities`, containing objects, which **may** contain date ranges; sorry I wasn't specific enough. But I believe I suggest the opposite--don't "query `availabilities`", iterate `availabilities` and build the collection of date statuses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply achieve this by defining a `startDate` and an `endDate` to represent the range of dates for the month you want to get the details. For demo purpose, I am using July month range.

```
const startDate = new Date("2023-07-01");
const endDate = new Date("2023-07-31");
```

Then, we will iterate over each date using a for loop, starting from the `startDate` and incrementing by one day until the `endDate`.

Within the loop, we check if the current date falls within the `startDateTime` and `endDateTime` range of any object in the array with the availabilityType `blackout`. If it does, the `isBooked` variable is set to `true`, indicating that the date is booked. Otherwise, `isBooked` remains `false`, indicating that the date is available.

Finally, we push an object to the `allDates` array for each date, setting the date property to the formatted date string and the available property to either `booked` or `available` based on the isBooked value.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const array = [
  {
    "_id": "64b03ed794d87927a3066e13",
    "startDateTime": "2023-07-07T18:00:00.000Z",
    "endDateTime": "2023-07-12T15:00:00.000Z",
    "availabilityType": "blackout"
  },
  {
    "_id": "64b03eb094d87927a3066ddb",
    "startDateTime": "2023-07-03T18:00:00.000Z",
    "endDateTime": "2023-07-06T15:00:00.000Z",
    "availabilityType": "blackout"
  }
];

const startDate = new Date("2023-07-01");
const endDate = new Date("2023-07-31");

const allDates = [];
for (let date = startDate; date <= endDate; date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1)) {
  const dateString = date.toISOString().split('T')[0];
  const isBooked = array.some(item => {
    const startDateTime = new Date(item.startDateTime);
    const endDateTime = new Date(item.endDateTime);
    return dateString >= startDateTime.toISOString().split('T')[0] && dateString <= endDateTime.toISOString().split('T')[0] && item.availabilityType === "blackout";
  });
  allDates.push({ date: dateString, available: isBooked ? "booked" : "available" });
}

console.log(allDates);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another take on it:

```js
const bookings=[{ "_id": "64b03ed794d87927a3066e13", "startDateTime": "2023-07-07T18:00:00.000Z",
  "endDateTime": "2023-07-12T15:00:00.000Z", "availabilityType": "blackout"},
 {"_id": "64b03eb094d87927a3066ddb", "startDateTime": "2023-07-03T18:00:00.000Z",
  "endDateTime": "2023-07-06T15:00:00.000Z", "availabilityType": "blackout" }];

 const monthCal={}; // set up the calendar for one month: July 2023   
 for (let d=1, m=6, y=2023, ld=new Date(y,m+1,0).getDate(); // set to 00:00h the following day
      d <= ld; d++ ) monthCal[`${y}-${String(m+1).padStart(2,"0")}-${String(d).padStart(2,"0")}`]=false;
      
bookings.forEach(b=>{
 // define the cut-off date ld as "00:00h", the day after endDateTime:
 const ld=new Date(b.endDateTime); ld.setDate(ld.getDate()+1); ld.setHours(0);
 for (let d=new Date(b.startDateTime); d < ld; d.setDate(d.getDate()+1)) 
  monthCal[d.toISOString().slice(0,10)]=true;
});

console.log(monthCal)

// or if you want the original output format:

console.log(Object.entries(monthCal).map(([date,v])=>({date,availabilityType:v?"booked":"available"})));
```

As the `monthCal` object allows the dates to be found directly, without using in inner loop, this might be slightly more efficient then scanning through an array of objects.